# How can i effectively detect Linux going low on RAM automatically?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, ram

The question is about effective way to monitor system RAM usage.

For example i have some Dax DIMM device that can be mmaped to use it's memory in application.
This memory is not always used and i want to give this memory to OS for general use so each application can access it without manual mmap.

How can i catch running low on memory kernel event and perform actions accordingly?

As far as i know it's possible to subscribe to `memory.pressure_level` as described here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt

If i understood correctly, all levels of such notifications will trigger after system is already performing swapping, but i want to give more memory to the system in advance, to not allow it to starve on RAM.

Is there any mechanism to perform the task in more efficient way?

Comment: A duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362833/how-to-trigger-action-on-low-memory-condition-in-linux ?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I've seen this question. This is exactly where i got the info about memory pressure. But the article it points to marked as "severely outdated". So question is more about how to do so in a more modern/efficient way. Any advises on my specific case with DAX are also highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are certain widgets in linux whoch when enabled can show the ram and cup usage in the runtime . Do check it out on the major linux distributions like mint , ubuntu , kali , debian etc.

Comment: The thing is I don’t want to use widgets or any side applications. I need some kernel mechanism to subscribe to such event. Like cgroups memory pressure, but more flexible, to be able to tell if system reached some threshold ( for example uses 90% of available memory) including page cache and anonymous mmap. So basically I want to get event before system starts memory reclamation

Comment: Please, spell check your answer and use proper grammar (`RAM` instead of `ram` and so on).